# Jquery plugin issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Ok so I just can't get it how to share settings across jquery plugin, no matter what I do my settings get overridden when looping trough elements. Here is my code:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var default_settings = { 
        auto_start: false,
        tools: {}
    };

    function test(settings){
        //here is the problem it gets wrong element
        settings.tools.progress_bar.animate({
            width: "100%"
        });
    }

    var methods = {
        init: function(element, options){
            var settings = $.extend({}, default_settings, options);

            settings.tools.progress_bar = $('<div class="test"></div>');

            $(element).append(
                settings.tools.progress_bar
            );

            if(settings.auto_start)
                test(settings);

            $.data(element, "settings", settings);
        },

        start: function(){
            var settings = $.data(this, "settings");

            test(settings);
        }
    }

    $.fn.ajaxupload = function(method, options){
        return this.each(function(){
            if(methods[method])
                return methods[method].apply(this, [options]);
            else if(typeof method === 'object' || !method)
                return methods.init(this, method);
        });
    }
})( jQuery);
```

I need to be able to loop trough multiple elements, and later on call public functions to start some actions or something else, like this:

```
$(".container").ajaxupload();

$(".container2").ajaxupload();

//even though I call for container it will run animation for container2
$(".container").ajaxupload("start");
```

I have also made [**jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/jupSp/3/) but at least to me at the moment it barely works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simpy replace

```
var settings = $.extend({}, default_settings, options);
```

with

```
var settings = $.extend(true, {},  default_settings, options);
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jupSp/12/

Without deep copy (first argument is true) it copies only the first level of object and in your case it resulted in 
`settings.tools` pointing to `default_settings.tools` and calling `settings.tools.progress_bar = $('<div class="test"></div>');` you override `default_settings.tools.progress_bar` and the last progress_bar is attached to all elements.